# How do I use jquery autocomplete to display a different list after a selection is made?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

So I have a textfield with an autocomplete attached to it working fine.

Here's what I want to happen:

1. The user types some letters into the textfield
2. The user is presented with the autocomplete suggestions list
3. The user selects an item from the suggestion list
4. The textfield is populated with the chosen item
5. The user is immediately presented with another suggestion list composed from a specified array

Basically, after the user makes their selection I want to present them with boolean operators - "AND"/"OR". The textfield is for a search application. I want to facilitate users searching for multiple topics e.g. "Apples AND Bananas".

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 2 different arrays? or do you want to separate multiple suggestions from same array with AND/OR?

Comment: I want to use a different array.

Comment: Do you mean you want a different array only from second word onwards (Total 2 arrays)? Or Do you want many arrays separately for each word?

Comment: The user must select a boolean operator before continuing. If the user selects a boolean the normal autocomplete function will resume.
The autocomplete does an ajax call for the list

Comment: So there would be two data sources, the result set from  the ajax call and a hard coded array of the booleans

Comment: How do you want the user to select the boolean? Is it by radio buttons below the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select event of autocomplete

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
    // Write your code here
    // preferably update your source of tags. Like,
    // availableTags = [New tag1, New tag2, ...];
} );
```

Comment: how do I make the list with the boolean options appear

Comment: sorry couldnt reply, was busy. And moreover, I didnt know how to make the boolean options appear. :)